# SQLite+FMDB: DELETE takes too much time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, fmdb

The setup: Mac OS 10.12, SQLite 3.16 FMDB 2.6.2

I want to delete some record with field "1-2-3" in column X (format of this field includes dashes). The record exists in table.

The table is large (>1M records), each record contains 2 fields, each one is reference (foreign key) to record in other table. Which means the aforementioned record references records in 2 other tables.

Pragmas defined: **synchronous**=full, **locking_mode**=exclusive, **secure_delete**=off.

So the relevant code looks like:

```
[queue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) 
             {
BOOL res;
res=[db executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM tbl WHERE X==?;",@"1-2-3"];
}]
```

just hangs the *sqlite3_step()* function - it is called and returns after long time.

Same with multiple rows deletion:

```
[queue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) 
             {
BOOL res;
res=[db executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM tbl WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM tbl WHERE X=some_value LIMIT 10);"];
}]
```

*sqlite3_step()* hangs and returns after long time - several minutes. 10 rows are finally off.

All queries performed on single thread synchronously.

I wonder what can be wrong...

UPDATE: the INSERT operation succeeds.